# Ubuntu On Stick: How it uses RAM

Tags: ram

I want to make an ubuntu to go, have it installed in my flashdrive or harddrive (or if you can recommend a better portable drive where I should install it) so that I can use it anywhere.

Question is what RAM does it use? How?

Does it's RAM usage function the same as dualboot OS? Or does it use virtual RAM from the same flashdrive where I installed it to? Or somewhere else I am clueless about?

And I hope there's also an explanation because I am not knowledgeable on these things.

Comment: If you install Ubuntu using a persistent method (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent) to install Ubuntu to thumb-drive the ram will be used the same as if installed on a hdd.  If however you use a 'live' media written to thumb-drive / (or root) [virtual-cow] file system is created in RAM so you have less ram available for programs, and the virtual-fs / has limited space - but RAM used is still only your system ram (on your machine's motherboard).  Live mode doesn't use 'swap' if that's what your question is about; you can control a persistent-install in using swap..